# How to calculate a value row that is based on the previous value in the same column (in R)?

Tags: r, sum, lag

For a time series analysis, I have a data frame that is based on periods. I have a column with starters and a column with patients who discontinue therapy. Now I want to calculate the current users of therapy per period. I calculated the difference between 'starters' and 'discontinue'  as an intermediate step.

```
> df <- data.frame(
period = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
starters = c(595, 113, 36, 489, 28, 101),
discontinue = c(0, 11, 6, 8, 14, 8))

> df$difference <- df$starters - df$discontinue
> df

  period starters discontinue difference
1      1      595           0        595
2      2      113          11        102
3      3       36           6         30
4      4      489           8        481
5      5       28          14         14
6      6      101           8         93
```

To calculate current users, I would like to add a column 'current.users' with initial value = `df$difference[1]` and adds the difference each row. Output should look like:

```
> df
  period starters discontinue difference current.users
1      1      595           0        595           595
2      2      113          11        102           697
3      3       36           6         30           727
4      4      489           8        481          1208
5      5       28          14         14          1222
6      6      101           8         93          1315
```

I tried to use for loops and data.table, but I can not calculate the next value in the column based on the previous value in the same column. Does anyone know the correct code for this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  mutate(difference = starters - discontinue, 
         current.users = cumsum(difference))

  period starters discontinue difference current.users
1      1      595           0        595           595
2      2      113          11        102           697
3      3       36           6         30           727
4      4      489           8        481          1208
5      5       28          14         14          1222
6      6      101           8         93          1315
```

Without the difference column

```
df %>%  
  mutate(current.users = cumsum(starters - discontinue))

  period starters discontinue current.users
1      1      595           0           595
2      2      113          11           697
3      3       36           6           727
4      4      489           8          1208
5      5       28          14          1222
6      6      101           8          1315
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple `cumsum` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  period = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
  starters = c(595, 113, 36, 489, 28, 101),
  discontinue = c(0, 11, 6, 8, 14, 8))

df$difference <- df$starters - df$discontinue
# cumsum
df$current.users <- cumsum(df$difference)
df
#>   period starters discontinue difference current.users
#> 1      1      595           0        595           595
#> 2      2      113          11        102           697
#> 3      3       36           6         30           727
#> 4      4      489           8        481          1208
#> 5      5       28          14         14          1222
#> 6      6      101           8         93          1315
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, I was thinking way to difficult, but this (simple) solution works!

Comment: @Mnn, Great to hear that it solved your problem!